# Why do these loops invoke `.iter().cloned()` on the array being iterated over?

Tags: rust, iterator

I was trying to follow this [guide](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/implementing.html#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to,do%20just%20that!) to learn Rust and WebAssembly, and couldn't wrap my head around this code snippet.

```rust
fn live_neighbor_count(&self, row: u32, column: u32) -> u8 {
    let mut count = 0;
    for delta_row in [self.height - 1, 0, 1].iter().cloned() {
        for delta_col in [self.width - 1, 0, 1].iter().cloned() {
            // ... details don't matter
        }
    }
    count
}
```

What's the point of using `.iter().cloned()` after the 2 arrays? Is there any benefit of doing that?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31217679/2864740

Comment: With a literal array of integers like this there is no point, you might as well do `for delta_row in [self.height - 1, 0, 1]`. For other types of data it might be required to allow the code to compile, as shown in the answer linked by @user2864740

Comment: Note that using array directly in `for` loop requires it to implement `IntoIterator`, which they didn't do until 1.53 - https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html#impl-IntoIterator; so the code by @Jmb would not compile in 1.52 and earlier. The guide is probably simply not yet updated and/or intentionally keeps the MSRV for provided code relatively low.